# Need to write \x0A char for record sperator

Tags: unix

I need to write a output file as shown below:

```
AAB   BBCC   DD\x0DEE\x0DFF
```

`\x0D` - is a hexa declmal char, I need to write it in a single line (file) ?

I am using `UNIX/Shell` scripts.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Kishore

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this, using octal?

```
echo -n AAB BBC DD$'\015'EE$'\015'FF | od -xc
0000000      4141    2042    4242    2043    4444    450d    0d45    4646
       A   A   B       B   B   C       D   D  \r   E   E  \r   F   F
```

Or this using a Return character?

```
echo -n AAB BBC DD$'\r'EE$'\r'FF | od -xc
0000000      4141    2042    4242    2043    4444    450d    0d45    4646
       A   A   B       B   B   C       D   D  \r   E   E  \r   F   F
```